# XNA 2D physic engine with deformable objects

Tags: xna, physics

May be anybody know XNA 2D physic engine with objects looks like objects from "World Of Goo" game? not only hard objects but objects with deformation.

Thanks in advise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice list of physics engines [here](http://www.nelxon.com/191/xdsk/).  Maybe one of these will help you.